# $G \to G$, $g \mapsto ng$ is an isomorphism implies $G$ is a $\Bbb Q$-vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces

Let $G$ be an abelian group, and suppose that the map $G \to G$, $g \mapsto ng$ is an isomorphism for each positive integer $n$. Then is $G$ a $\Bbb Q$-vector space? It seems obvious, but I cannot write down a proof. How do I have to start?

Comment: I would start by carefully defining $ag$ for $a\in \Bbb Q$ and $g\in G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the ring homomorphism
\begin{align}
&\mu:\Bbb Z\to\operatorname{End}(G)&
&n\mapsto(x\in G\mapsto nx)
\end{align}
The set $S=\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}$ is a multipicative submonoid of $\Bbb Z$ and for every $s\in S$, $\mu(s)$ is invertible in $\operatorname{End}(G)$.
By universal property of ring localization, the ring homomorphism $\mu$ extends to a ring homomorphism $\bar\mu:\Bbb Q\to\operatorname{End}(G)$ by
$$\bar\mu\left(\frac as\right)=\frac{\mu(a)}{\mu(s)}$$
for every $a\in\Bbb Z$ and $s\in S$ and this makes $G$ a $\Bbb Q$ vecor space.